# Show that the product of two unipotent upper triangle matrices is an unipotent upper triangular matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let be $A,B \in M_{n,n}$ two unipotent upper triangle matrices. Show that the product $AB$ is an unipotent upper triangle matrix.

I'm considering that maybe to prove that the product of two upper triangle matrix is an upper triangle matrix could help me to show it. I would appreciate any kind of help, thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried any small examples?  The product of two upper triangular matrices is upper triangular and a few small examples will give you lots of hints.

Comment: Hint: what are the diagonal elements of a triangular unipotent matrix?